# Not able to read JSON from service

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nsdictionary, nsdata

I am implementing forget password service in which I would pass an email address and it would return JSON to acknowledge about the sent email. The issue is that I am unable to read the response string in json, and my exception message is shown that data parameter is nil, but if I view the url in my web browser the service looks fine as mentioned below.
my code is:

```
NSURL *url = [LokalmotionCommonTask getURLForgotPassword:emailFieldTxt.text];

    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];

    @try {
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization 
                                  JSONObjectWithData:data //1
                                  options:0 
                                  error:&error];

        NSLog(@"%@", [jsonDict objectForKey:@"response"]);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"forgot password exception: %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
    }
```

and the service response I get in my web browser is like this:

```
{"status":400,"response":"Your request to change password is already sent. Please check your email."}
```

Exception:

```
forgot password exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: data parameter is nil
```

Comment: Where does it "crashes" exactly?

Comment: it reads line is which jsonDict is instantiated and then exception is thrown

Comment: well there you have it, data is nil.

Comment: but as you see in the service response, it does contain a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Objective-C exceptions are only used for fatal errors, not recoverable errors. Instead just check for nil data:

If you need to know what was the reason for failure, use:

```
NSError* error;
NSURL *url = [LokalmotionCommonTask getURLForgotPassword:emailFieldTxt.text];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url options:NULL error:&error];
if (data) {
    NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization 
                              JSONObjectWithData:data //1
                              options:0 
                              error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", [jsonDict objectForKey:@"response"]);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"forgot password error, %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

There is a naming convention error: `getURLForgotPassword:`
A method name that begins with "get" implies that there will be a return by reference parameter. Better to just name the method: `forgotPasswordURL:`

These two things, exceptions and accessors prefixed with get are a basic difference from Jave.

Comment: still null. is it due to that the service response is not as per standard? like can 'response' directly contain a string or it should contain an array of items?

Comment: NSLog() the url and validate it. See my updated example code with the error message. Also, consider changing your question to indicate that the provided response message it what you expect, not what you receive, the way it is now is confusing.

Comment: changes didnt work. I want to get the response in NSDictionary and it is not getting, rather getting null, thats the problem, still confusing?

Comment: NSLog() the url and validate it.

Comment: Exceptions are thrown as a result of programmer errors. Data coming in from the outside are not handled with exceptions. You don't catch exceptions. When an exception happens, you know there is an error in your code, and you fix that error. In this case, passing nil to the JSON parser is a programmer error. Don't catch the exception, just don't do it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There error says `data parameter is nil`. So the variable you pass for the JSON-date probably is `nil`.
`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]` probably returns nil since an error occured. Try logging that.

Also, even if it is only a small file you request, I would go for an asynchronous request in order not to block the UI.

Comment: I have mentioned the response above and its worth two values.

Comment: How can you know how it looks? Did you `NSLog` it?

Comment: i saw it in my web browser, the thing is that it is ok while i see from my web browser, but NSData is getting null

Comment: So you did actually not mention the response you get on iOS. Try logging the url you passed for getting the data.

Comment: i logged the url and it looks fine and is getting response on web browser, but there is no response in iOS

Comment: Can you please post what gets logged + the code where you create the URL?

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same problem, problem was that i have given extra space in the url string that was url string @"   http:...." corrected it by removing space in the start of url string @"https:...."

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: But i was facing exact the same problem asked in this question and it helped me it was due to extra space in start of url string, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved that by fixing service URL, my url was not encoded and had spaces inline